# Asp.net MVC File Upload Does Not Show File Input

Tags: asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I need upload image with model. But editorfor showing a different html control.

[image]

Model

```
<Required(ErrorMessage:="Logo is Required")>
<DataType(DataType.Upload)>
<Display(Name:="Logo", ResourceType:=GetType(RestaurantModelStrings))>
Public Property Logo As HttpPostedFileBase
```

View

```
   @Html.EditorFor(Function(m) m.Logo)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TextBoxFor` like this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.Logo, new { type = "file" })
```

Comment: Sorry its generated file input but now doest fill my model. it is coming null

Comment: what is Function(m) perfrming??

Comment: for vb.net lambda . And i think problem from ajax.beginfrom. ajax.beginform does not support file upload. i could not fix this

Comment: what is the solition of this problem ?

Comment: i mostly use this plugin for file uploading via ajax:http://powerdotnetcore.com/asp-net-mvc/asp-net-mvc-simple-ajax-file-upload-using-jquery